# Where would iPhone questions go?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There's a [Stack for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/) and a [Stack for Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/), but I can't seem to find a Stack for iPhones.  Where can I ask a question related to iPhones? Specifically, having trouble connecting one to a PC that doesn't have iTunes on it.  Would that go in [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: when you think different, you gotta [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on main meta

Answer (score 11):

iPhone (and Apple-related products) are fully on-topic on [Ask Different (Apple.SE)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) also accepts [iPhone](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iphone)-related questions *partially*. From their [tour](https://superuser.com/tour),

> Don't ask about... Videogames, consoles, or other electronic devices, **unless they connect to your computer**